# Find function names alone in all files with a given extension

Tags: regex, shell, find

I tried

```
find "$1" -print | grep -i '.*[.]c' | sort
```

to find out all the files in a folder that have .c file extensions.

1) But I also need to printout each c file`s content. For example, assuming that there are "practice.c" and "practice_1.c" files in test folder,

```
test/practice.c:

void function(int loc)
int function1()

test/practice_1.c:

void function2()
char function3(char locc)
```

like this... I have to print out only the function names, not all the contents.
If I use -exec cat, it prints out all of its contents so I am stuck here.

-----------------------edit --------------------------------------

```
find "$1" -type f -name *.c -exec echo {} \; -exec grep "(*)" {} \; | sed 's/{//g'
```

When I use the above code, this prints out as

```
test/practice.c
void function(int loc)
int function1()
test/practice_1.c
void function2()
char function3(char locc)
```

How can I make it to output as:

```
test/practice.c:
void function(int loc)
int function1()

test/practice_1.c:
void function2()
char function3(char locc)
```

(need to add semicolon after the file name and also a new line after a one file display is done...)

Comment: You need to scope out your question in two parts. The first part is more of a regex question to match function prototypes, then to to list the files. You should split it up and add `regex` tag to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one. if this fulfills your criteria.

```
find "$1" -type f -name *.c -exec echo {}":" \; -exec grep "(*)" {} \; |sed 's/{//g' | awk '{if(($0~/:/)&&(NR>1)){$0="\n"$0};print}'
```

`find "$1" -type f -name *.c -exec echo {}":" \;` ###this will find all the .c files in $1 folder.  so *.c means file names ending with .c and it also append : in filenames in output.

`-exec grep "(*)" {} \;` ###this will grep within the files searched for line having ( and ) both round brackets which we use in command c function syntax

`| sed 's/{//g'`  ###all the things searched are piped to this sed command. As the function name has { after their name declaration so removing it here

`awk '{if($0~/:/){$0="\n"$0};print}'`  ###here we are appending \n in the start of line which contains :

Comment: thanks! but this one prints out all the content of a file like:
#include <stdlib.h>
but I need to print only the function names ;)
Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: I have added grep "(*)" in my answer. you have to give me regex to identify the function. Same regex I can add in grep

Comment: It prints out only the function names but { is added at the end of the function names, like:
char* file(char* name) {
Is there anyway to remove { ??

Comment: What I did is:
find "$1" -type f -name *.c -printf "$1:\n" -exec grep "(*)" {} \; | sed 's/{//g'
but this does not print file name, but only prints the folder name...
Could you please tell me how could this be fixed?

Comment: printf $1 will print only $1 not the files inside it. what is the issue with my code?  is it necessary to use print $1?

Comment: edited the answer again as per your need. don't change question again. :P :P

Comment: Okay I will create a new question :) I will vote you and would you please answer my new question?

Comment: done now. Added awk in end to format the code. Now semicolon(:) and new line (enter)both are added

Answer (score 1):

## Finding C Files

First of all, don't grep `find`'s output. You can use `find`'s `-iname` option instead. To also allow filenames with newlines in them use `-print0` instead of `-print`.

```
find "$1" -iname '*.c' -print0 | sort -z
```

But there's an even better way: `bash`'s globstar (see **Putting Things Together**).

## Print Functions

In this case it would be better to use a dedicated program instead of hacking something together. [`ctags -x`](https://man.openbsd.org/ctags) or [`cscope`](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_man_page.html) seem to be up for the job. `ctags` output relies on the formatting of your files, so we auto-format them using `indent`.

To print the function definitions from one file as in your example use the following function:

```
printFunctions() {
    printf "%s:\n\n" "$1"             # filename at the top
    indent -l0 -npsl < "$1" > tmp.c
    ctags -x tmp.c |
    awk '$2 == "function"' |
    tr -s ' ' |
    cut -d' ' -f5-
    rm tmp.c
    echo                              # empty line at the end
}
```

## Putting Things Together

```
short -s globstar
for cfile in **/*.c; do
    printFunctions "$cfile"
done
```

Comment: Nit pick: the default awk action is `print`, so no need for `{ print }`.

Comment: also it will ignore the void main() or int main() functions in C because in those lines $2 will not be equal to "function".

Comment: @ShravanYadav I just tried my function with `int main ()`, `void main ()` and `int main (int argc, char *argv[])`. All three versions are listed as functions. What does `ctags -x` print on your system?

Comment: ctags is fine but awk will filter rows only with $2=="function".

Comment: @ShravanYadav The `awk` part should also be correct. As I said, `printFunctions yourFile.c` will print `int main()` if there is a function `int main()` inside your file. Please note that `ctag -x` prefixes each function with the keyword `function` in column two, no matter what that name of the function is.